# univariate regression in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-lab

Need to run multiple single-factor (univariate) regression models in python between a column in a dataframe and several other columns in the same dataframe

-

### [image]

so based on the image, i want to run regression models between x1 & dep, x2 & dep and so on and so forth

Want to output - beta, intercept, R-sq, p-value, SSE, AIC, BIC, Normality test of residuals etc

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where you are facing a problem.

Comment: I have done this exercse on SAS Base 9.4. However, I am trying to do this on python. you can see how my datafraem looks like based on the image I have uploaded in the post. Let me know ur solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two options you can use here. One is the popular [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) library. It is used as follows

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)  # where X is your feature data and y is your target
reg.score(X, y)  # R^2 value
>>> 0.87
reg.coef_  # slope coeficients
>>> array([1.45, -9.2])
reg.intercept_  # intercept
>>> 6.1723...
```

There are not many other statistics you can use with scikit.

Another option is [statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html) which offers far richer detail into the statistics of the model

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

# generate some synthetic data
nsample = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
X = np.column_stack((x, x**2))
beta = np.array([1, 0.1, 10])
e = np.random.normal(size=nsample)

X = sm.add_constant(X)
y = np.dot(X, beta) + e

# fit the model and get a summary of the statistics
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())

                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       1.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  1.000
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                 4.020e+06
Date:                Mon, 08 Jul 2019   Prob (F-statistic):          2.83e-239
Time:                        02:07:22   Log-Likelihood:                -146.51
No. Observations:                 100   AIC:                             299.0
Df Residuals:                      97   BIC:                             306.8
Df Model:                           2                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          1.3423      0.313      4.292      0.000       0.722       1.963
x1            -0.0402      0.145     -0.278      0.781      -0.327       0.247
x2            10.0103      0.014    715.745      0.000       9.982      10.038
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        2.042   Durbin-Watson:                   2.274
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.360   Jarque-Bera (JB):                1.875
Skew:                           0.234   Prob(JB):                        0.392
Kurtosis:                       2.519   Cond. No.                         144.
==============================================================================
```

You can see that statsmodels offer much more details, such as the AIC, BIC, t-statistics etc.

Comment: my dataframe essentially looks the image i have embedded in my post. My utlimate output should have the list of models I ran with betas in separate columns, r-sq in separate columns etc.

Comment: Yes, well my answer provides how to do that. Data pre-processing / structuring is left at your discretion. If you want to get particular columns from your dataframe into a numpy array to fit the model on, you can use `X = df[['x1','x2']].values` and `y = df[['Dependent']]`