# performing univariate regression on all columns of pandas dataframe i.e column-wise univariate regression

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Using scikit-learn or other suitable library I can perform univariate linear regression for a column against a dependent variable. If I were to do similar univariate regression between all pairs of dependent variable and independent variable then I can run a for loop and do it.

But is there a vectorised way to do so without the use of for loop?

For loop implementation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'y': np.random.randn(20),
  'x1': np.random.randn(20), 
  'x2': np.random.randn(20),
  'x3': np.random.randn(20)})

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
for i in range(3):
    t=LinearRegression().fit(df[['x'+str(i+1)]],df[['y']])
    print(t.coef_)
    print(t.intercept_)
```

Vectorized Implementation:

??

Related question with incorrect answer.
[univariate regression in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56930145/univariate-regression-in-python)

Comment: I am curious about your intention in doing so. The overhead of for loop should be immaterial when compared to the regression fit operation, i.e. y_hat = (X^T X)^-1 X^T y.

Comment: I hope vectorized implementation would be much faster and clean. Since I don't have one, I am not able to compare. P.S I have features in the order or millions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scikit-learn APIs are not natively designed for your use case. I'm also not aware of a single high-level function that does what you're describing. However, this is a great problem for Dask, which will allow you to parallelize this quite nicely with very few changes to your code.

Dask's `delayed` API allows you to smoothly parallelize for-loops like in your example. I highly recommend checking out the introductory [tutorial](https://tutorial.dask.org/01_dask.delayed.html).

Original:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
​
np.random.seed(12)
​
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'y': np.random.randn(20),
  'x1': np.random.randn(20), 
  'x2': np.random.randn(20),
  'x3': np.random.randn(20)})
​
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
for i in range(3):
    t=LinearRegression().fit(df[['x'+str(i+1)]],df[['y']])
    print(t.coef_, t.intercept_)
[[0.12973704]] [0.11022991]
[[0.09058823]] [0.02903383]
[[0.12020571]] [0.02941156]
```

Dask Version (using `delayed`):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from dask import delayed
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask
​
client = Client() # set up a local Dask cluster
​
​
def fit_ols(df, feature_col, target_col="y"):
    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(df[[feature_col]], df[target_col])
    return clf.coef_[0], clf.intercept_
​
results = []
​
for i in range(3):
    xcol = f"x{i+1}"
    res = delayed(fit_ols)(df, xcol)
    results.append(res)
​
dask.compute(results)
([(0.1297370368274274, 0.11022990787315554),
  (0.09058823367556357, 0.029033826351961462),
  (0.12020570872010947, 0.02941156049324152)],)
```

The key change is wrapping your logic into a function. With that, we can rely on `delayed` to add tasks to a task graph and then call `compute` on the graph to execute the tasks in parallel.

Editing to include an example of how you might want to do this at a larger scale, since you have millions of columns. Note the `scatter` operation and passing of the `future`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from dask import delayed
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
import dask

# set up a local cluster
# my laptop has limited CPU cores, so only using two to parallelize
client = Client(n_workers=2, threads_per_worker=1)

# Setup data
np.random.seed(12)

nrows = 10000
ncols = 1000
df = pd.DataFrame({f"x{i}": np.random.randn(nrows) for i in range(ncols)})
df['y'] = np.random.randn(nrows)

# scatter the data to the workers beforehand
data_future = client.scatter(df, broadcast=True)

# Many calls to linear regression, parallelized with Dask
def fit_ols(df, feature_col, target_col="y"):
    clf = LinearRegression()
    clf.fit(df[[feature_col]], df[target_col])
    return clf.coef_[0], clf.intercept_
​
results = []
​
for i in range(df.shape[1]-1):
    xcol = f"x{i}"
    # note how i'm passing the scattered data future
    res = delayed(fit_ols)(data_future, xcol)
    results.append(res)
​
res = dask.compute(results)
res[0][:5]
[(0.01898470494963711, -0.0013691188314244067),
 (-0.018210714678412274, -0.0015618953728564272),
 (-0.013344320263479937, -0.001588615271127849),
 (-0.006330810820098386, -0.0016927025190818918),
 (0.007960791021720603, -0.0016594945951821688)]
```

I've attached a screenshot of the dashboard showing the computation in progress:

[image: Dask dashboard of the]